# Adding cocoapods-art plugin to podspec for private repo dependency

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I've been using a private cocoapod library in my app which is installed via cocoapods-art. Now I have created a wrapper for this library and want to make our own cocoapod for it so we can use it into multiple other applications. But I don't know if it's possible to use a cocoapods-art plugin in the podspec file
I couldn't find an example on how to add a cocoapods-art lib as a dependency in the podspec file. The way it's installed in my Podfile:

```
  plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
    'PRIVATE_REPO'
  ]
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
```